# Вывод данных из одного input в другой по клику на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Получилось взять данные `input.transfer_number_post`, но не получается записать в другой `input.transfer_number_get`, помогите разобраться плиз

```js
function transferNumber() {

  var postNumberPhone = document.getElementsByClassName('transfer_number_post');
  var postValue = postNumberPhone[0].value;
  var getNumberPhone = document.getElementsByClassName('transfer_number_get');
  var getValue = getNumberPhone[0].value;
  getValue += postValue;

  console.log(postValue);
  console.log(getValue);
}
```

```css
.card-block__form {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="card-block__form" action="#" name="myForm3">
  <input class="transfer_number_post" type="tel" id="tel_3" placeholder="+380 (__) ___-__-__">
  <input type="button" value="Купить" data-modal-name="modal_window" onclick="transferNumber()">
</form>

<form class="form" action="#" name="myForm2" onsubmit="return(validateEnergetic());">
  <input type="text" name="Name2" placeholder="Имя Фамилия">
  <input class="transfer_number_get" type="tel" name="Phone2" id="tel_2" placeholder="+380 (__) ___-__-__">
  <input type="text" name="Dept2" placeholder="Отдел">
  <textarea placeholder="Текст вашей заявки"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что есть код, но описать что откуда и куда брать не помешало бы

Comment: добавил информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function push(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var val = document.getElementById("inputId1").value;
   document.getElementById("inputId2").value = val;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputId1" type="text" value="test value">
<input id="inputId2" type="text" value="">
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="push(event)">взять из одного input и положить в другой</a>
```

Comment: а можно сделать тоже самое только не по id а по class?

Comment: @max так элементов с одним и тем же классом может быть много

Comment: я просто по id привязал другой скрипт, и эта же форма есть на других страницах

Comment: а можно по уникальному атрибуту такое сделать?

Comment: @max ну так вы можете ссылаться на этот id в разных местах.

Comment: @max это можно сделать и через уникальный атрибут и через уникальный класс, но так делать не надо, на каждый input делается свой Id и этот элемент по этому Id может быть получен в любом месте.

Comment: @max если у вас уже есть Id который используется в другом месте, используйте его же и тут, он для этого и создан. Задача Id позволить в JavaScript или Css ссылаться на этот элемент и находить его (из скольки угодно мест).

Comment: Спасибо, я понял

Comment: @max если вам мой ответ помог, можете так же отметить его лайком.